# read matrix from mtx file and store in C array

Tags: c, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have an mtx file . A.mtx and I need to store the matrix values in a single dimension C array and also the rows and columns. can someone help please ?

Comment: The answer to all "no idea how to start" questions is: "read, find working examples, try, fix, redo". I.e. read some text book or tutorial, find a HelloWorld or sample code, try to change it in small steps towards your goal, test, debug; then try the next iteration. Once you got something and it does not work for the very small change you made away from something working, then it is time to ask a focused question here, according to [ask] and maybe using the compromise described here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Before going around schooling everyone its better to put yourself in someone elses shows. mtx files with c are not simple. this is a very simple and focused question how to store an mtx file into an array.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if [this NIST page](https://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/formats.html) has info that you are seeking. There are descriptions of the formats and also some links to I/O libraries in different languages.